# mysql not accepting tablename as it is

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, hmvc

i m working on a project that displays user, admin and superadmin panel and uses HMVC for functionality. The main problem here is that when i login through superadmin user, the data must be fetched from a table named 'users' but instead when the 'users' variable is passed in `$this->load->model('user_model', 'users');` and if i run the project, it is showing DB error as

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146
Table 'interview_panel.user' doesn't exist
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM `user`
Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/ba-tool/system/database/DB_driver.php
Line Number: 691
```

so basically problem is i m sending parameter as 'users' and the value passed is 'user' without "s" and the same problem is happening with another table in my DB that causes the whole project to stop. Neither i am able to find how the flow of project is working for db queries.

**CI Bootstrap Version: Build 20170324, CI Version: 3.1.3**

Comment: as mentioned you have table named users but you are fetching table user.Please check table name again

Comment: I would also check if that is actually the line that is causing the error and you do not try to actually load `user` somewhere else (e.g. comment it out if it doesn't break your code, replace it with a different table name, check for 'user' in your code, log something, ...).

Comment: Show the code where you make the call to the model and the model function called.

Comment: The line `this->load->model('user_model', 'users');` has nothing to do with table names. What that does is set the name of the model class to "users" and nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

thanks, everyone for the help i found the issue. It was due to xampp version 7.3.9 and php installed along with it, then i installed xampp 7.2.26 and it resolved the issue, there some difference in configs of both php versions that causes this error